# How to get Junit 4 to ignore a Base Test Class?

Tags: junit, junit4

I have a base class for many tests that has some helper methods they all need.

It does not by itself have any tests on it, but JUnit (in eclipse) is invoking the test runner on it and complaining that there are no methods to test.

How can I make it ignore this class?

I know I could add a `dummyTest` method that would solve the problem, but it would also appear for all the children classes.

Suggestions?

Comment: It is and still gets run

Comment: See similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/672466/junit-how-to-avoid-no-runnable-methods-in-test-utils-classes

Comment: i just came to know that incase we write a testcase then there should be atleast 1 @Test method inside the testcase and its mandotory. Other wise it would give us initialization error. Is it true?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Use to `@Ignore` annotation. It also works on classes.
See this one:

```
@Ignore public class IgnoreMe {
                        @Test public void test1() { ... }
                        @Test public void test2() { ... }
                }
```

> Also, you can annotate a class
>   containing test methods with @Ignore
>   and none of the containing tests will
>   be executed.

Source: [JUnit JavaDoc](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Ignore.html)

Comment: I agree that this should work, so +1. Except with netbeans 6.2 and jUnit 4.5 @ignore is listed as only being valid for Methods.

Comment: Looking it up and Libary's called 4.5 but the jar is junit4-1.jar weird.  Accepted your answer. Thanks.

Comment: Can you point me to valid reference where it says @Ignore is valid for methods only from junit 4.5? I can't seem to find it.

Comment: ...and if I want to ignore test for all methods except one (instead of putting @ignore above each method)?

Answer (score 34):

Just as a note, I'd always recommend giving a reason for the ignore:

```
@Ignore("This test will prove bug #123 is fixed, once someone fixes it")
```

I'm hoping the junit xml report formatter, used when running tests from ant, will one day include the ignored count (and the reasons) along with pass, fail, and error.

Comment: Years passed, but the `bug #123` is not fixed yet..)

Answer (score 27):

Making the class `abstract` should be enough for JUnit 4. If it doesn't work, double check which version of JUnit you're using.

This also communicates your intent that this is just a fragment of a test.

It also prevents JUnit from counting the tests in the class as "ignored" (so the final count of ignored tests will be what you expect).

Alternatively, rename the class. Most of the runners use the class name to determine which classes are tests and which are helpers. In Maven with the default settings, you just have to make sure the base class doesn't begin or end with `Test` and doesn't end with `TestCase` (http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html)

Comment: The combination of @Ignore and abstract is excellet!

Comment: You do not need `@Ignore`. Abstract is enough (and best in my opinion)

Comment: With JUnit 4, `abstract` should be enough.

Comment: Way to go! With `@Ignore` and without `abstract`, I had unwanted skipped tests in my final report when building from command line with `mvn package`.

Answer (score 18):

### JUnit5 - @Disabled

`@Ignore` not exit in the future version, If you are using JUnit5, you can use [`@Disabled`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-disabling) from JUnit Jupiter

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Disabled;
```

You can even use `@Disabled` with a comment `@Disabled("some comment here")`

#### Class

Annotate the class, will disable all the tests in the class :

```
@Disabled
public class DemoTest { }
```

---

```
@Disabled("some comment here")
public class DemoTest { }
```

#### Method

```
@Disabled
public void whenCaseThenResult() { }
```

---

```
@Disabled("some comment here")
public void whenCaseThenResult() { }
```

Comment: You are doing great, too. As always, too!

Answer (score 11):

There are three options:

1. In JUnit 4 or 5 its enough to make the base class **abstract**. If you use `@Igonre` attribute it will show it as an ignored test (and will add it to the total count of tests).
2. You can use the `@Ignore` annotation. This annotation also works for classes.
   The `@Ignore` test annotation is used to ignore particular tests or groups of tests in order to skip the build failure.

   ```
   @Ignore("Base class not yet ready") 
   class MyBaseClassTestCases {...}
   ```
3. You can change the name of the test class that **it will not have the word** *Test* (case sensitive) at the start or the end of the test name/or the word *TestCase* at the end.

Comment: Most relevant answer IMO.

Comment: abstract is definitively the way to go for a base test class

Answer (score 1):

Adding an empty test works.

```
@Test(expected = Test.None.class)
public void ATest() {}
```

Beware, adding it without `(expected = Test.None.class)` will add an "Add at least one assertion" sonar issue.