# No Runnable methods and Test class should have exactly one public zero-argument constructor

Tags: java, ant, selenium, junit

i got an error whenever i run my code in Ant, but on eclipse using (Run > JunitTest)it works well with no error.

**below is the error message i got when i generated the report:**

> **"Test class should have exactly one public zero-argument constructor"**
>
> java.lang.Exception: Test class should have exactly one public
>   zero-argument constructor at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>
> **"No Runnable methods"**
>   -java.lang.Exception: No runnable methods at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)

Please look on my code:

**This code has annotations (@)**

```
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.*;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;


public class ABMTLinks extends SeleneseTestCase {

    /*
     * Variables for PieChart
     */
    public static int
        iPass,
        iFail,
        iError,
        iLeft=800,
        iRight=600; 
    public static String
        sPieChartTitle = "Pie Chart",
        sPieChartName = "Pie Chart",    
        sPath = "c:\\temp\\pieChart.jpg";

    public static int iTotalTestCaseCtr, iSum;
    public static String
         HMT = "http://dev.abmt.igloo.com.au/GetInvolved/Hostamorningtea/tabid/165/Default.aspx";

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 1111, "*googlechrome", "http://www.google.com.ph/");
        selenium.start();
    }
    @Test
    public void testUntitled() throws Exception {
        selenium.open("/#hl=fil&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=harold&oq=harold&gs_l=hp.3..0l4.12830.13374.0.14277.6.6.0.0.0.2.745.2228.2-4j0j1j0j1.6.0...0.0...1c.ef1dV3OAuZg&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=55dc10243cd7c593&biw=1366&bih=624");

        String URL = HMT;
        if (URL.equals(HMT)
            ){
            iPass++;
            System.out.println("All pages redirects to each URL with no errors");           
        }
        else {
            iFail++;
            assertTrue("Test Case is Failed!", false);
            System.out.print("Failed");
        }
        iTotalTestCaseCtr++;
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        selenium.stop();
        iSum = iFail + iPass;
        if (iTotalTestCaseCtr == iSum) {
            PieChart chartABMT = new PieChart(iPass, iFail, iError, sPieChartName, sPieChartTitle,  iLeft, iRight, sPath) ;
            chartABMT.pack();
            chartABMT.setVisible(true);
        }   
    }   
}
```

**This code was inherited on the above code to generate a Pie Chart and saves it on a folder**

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;    
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartUtilities;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.labels.StandardPieSectionLabelGenerator;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PiePlot;
import org.jfree.data.general.DefaultPieDataset;
import org.jfree.data.general.PieDataset;

public class PieChart extends JFrame {

    public static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public PieChart(int iPass, int iFail, int iError, String applicationTitle, String chartTitle, int iLeft, int iRight, String sPath) {
        super(applicationTitle);
        PieDataset dataset = createDataset(iFail, iError, iPass);
        JFreeChart chart = createChart(dataset, chartTitle);
        ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
        chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(iLeft, iRight));
        setContentPane(chartPanel);
        String fileLocation =  sPath ;
        saveChart(chart, fileLocation);   

    }

    /**
     * Creates a sample dataset 
     */
    public  PieDataset createDataset(int iFail, int iError, int iPass) {
        DefaultPieDataset result = new DefaultPieDataset();
        result.setValue("Failed:", iFail);
        result.setValue("Error:", iError);
        result.setValue("Passed:", iPass);
        return result;    
    }

    /**
     * Creates a chart
     */
    public JFreeChart createChart(PieDataset dataset, String title) {

        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createPieChart(title,               // chart title
            dataset,                // data
            true,                   // include legend
            true,
            false);

        PiePlot plot = (PiePlot) chart.getPlot();
        plot.setLabelFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        plot.setCircular(false);
        plot.setLabelGap(0.02);
        plot.setLabelGenerator(new StandardPieSectionLabelGenerator("{0} {1} ({2})")); //Shows the total count and percentage for Failed/Passed/Error
        return chart;

    }
    public void saveChart(JFreeChart chart, String fileLocation) {
        String fileName = fileLocation;
        try {
            /**
             * This utility saves the JFreeChart as a JPEG First Parameter:
             * FileName Second Parameter: Chart To Save Third Parameter: Height
             * Of Picture Fourth Parameter: Width Of Picture
             */
            ChartUtilities.saveChartAsJPEG(new File(fileName), chart, 800, 600);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.err.println("Problem occurred creating chart.");
        }
    }

}
```

Below is my XML Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>

<project name="JUnitTest1" default="usage" basedir=".">
    <!-- Create a folder with date and time -->
    <tstamp prefix="start">
        <format property="dateTime" pattern="MM-dd-YYYY HH-MM-ss" />
    </tstamp>

    <property environment = "env"/>
    <property name="ws.home" value="${basedir}"/>
    <property name="ws.jars" value="C:/Selenium/selenium-2.24.1"/>
    <property name="Igloo.dest" value="${ws.home}/build"/>
    <property name="Igloo.src" value="${ws.home}/src"/>
    <property name="Igloo.reportsDir" value="C:/reports/report ${start.dateTime}"/>
    <propert name="junit.style.dir" value = "C:/xsl/junit-frames.xsl" />

    <path id="Igloo.path">
        <pathelement location="${Igloo.dest}" />
        <fileset dir = "${ws.jars}" >
            <include name = "*.jar" />
        </fileset>
    </path>

    <target name="setClassPath" unless="Igloo.classpath">
        <path id="classpath_jars">
            <fileset dir="${ws.jars}" includes="*.jar" />
        </path>

        <pathconvert pathsep=": "
            property = "Igloo.classpath"
            refid = "classpath_jars"/>
    </target>

    <target name="init" depends="setClassPath">
        <tstamp>
            <format property="start.time" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm ss" />
        </tstamp>

        <condition property="ANT"
            value = "${env.ANT_HOME}/bin/ant.bat"
            else = "${env.ANT_HOME}/bin/ant">
                <os family="windows" />
        </condition>
    </target>

    <!-- Clean -->
    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="${Igloo.dest}"/>
    </target>

    <!-- Compile -->
    <target name="compile" depends="init, clean">
        <delete includeemptydirs="true" quiet="true">
            <fileset dir="${Igloo.dest}" includes="**/*"/>
        </delete>

        <echo message="making directory..."/>
        <mkdir dir="${Igloo.dest}" />
        <echo message="classpath ...: ${Igloo.classpath}"/>
        <echo message="compiling..."/>

        <javac
            debug="true"
            destdir="${Igloo.dest}"
            srcdir="${Igloo.src}"
            target="1.7"
            classpath="${Igloo.classpath}"
        >
        </javac>

    </target>

    <!-- build -->
    <target name="build" depends="init">
    </target>

    <target name="usage">
        <echo>
            ant run will execute the test
        </echo>
    </target>

    <!-- Run -->
    <target name="run">
        <mkdir dir="${Igloo.reportsDir}" />
        <delete includeemptydirs="true" quiet="true">
            <fileset dir="${Igloo.reportsDir}" includes="**/*" />       
        </delete>
        <java jar="${ws.jars}" fork="true" spawn="true" />
        <junit fork="yes" haltonfailure="no" printsummary="yes">

            <classpath refid="Igloo.path" />
            <batchtest todir="${Igloo.reportsDir}" fork="true">
                <fileset dir="${Igloo.dest}">
                    <include name="ABMTLinks.class" /> 
                </fileset>
            </batchtest>
        <formatter type="xml" />
        <classpath refid="Igloo.path" />
        </junit>

            <junitreport todir="${Igloo.reportsDir}">
                <fileset dir="${Igloo.reportsDir}">
                    <include name="TEST-*.xml" />
                </fileset>
                <report todir="${Igloo.reportsDir}"/>       
            </junitreport>
    </target>
</project>
```

Please help.
[image: error message]

Comment: How does ABMTSuite look like?

Comment: that code comes from selenium, and i added a condition just to trace if the the test case is failed/passed, BTW just disregard the code inside the @Test, i just record that using selenium, that goes only on google site then type a search keyword and thats it. as you can see i forced this test to be passed on the if-else condition - just a test, and here it will call the PieChart.class to generate a Pie Chart and save it to the specified location. hope i answer your question. sorry for my english.

Comment: in ant you execute ABMTSuite, please show the code for the suite. Or change ant to use ABMTLinks.

Comment: I don't have a suite, in eclipse i only run my code ABMTLinks by (Run > Junit test) and works. while on ant, e.g my class folder: C:/workspace/ABMT-Test/: then from here i just type ant command in command prompt.. e.g 

C:/workspace/ABTM-Test/: ant clean
C:/workspace/ABTM-Test/: ant compile
C:/workspace/ABTM-Test/: ant run

Comment: you have suite, look at the junit task in your ant file!

Comment: is the constructor of SeleneseTestCase protected?

Comment: hmm i just only get that code on selenium, records it and convert the recorded to JUnit 4, then it shows that code on ABMTLinks - so i dont have constructor. sorry im only just a beginner on this java..

Comment: hope you can extend your patience in catching up all this..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451496/does-junit4-testclasses-require-a-public-no-arg-constructor - my issue also related on this.

Comment: SeleneseTestCase  is Junit3 and the annotations are Junit4. There is something wrong with selenium it seems. Try to get rid of extends SeleneseTestCase.

Comment: [This google search shows a lot of problems with SeleneseTestCase](https://www.google.de/search?q=SeleneseTestCase&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls={moz:distributionID}:{moz:locale}:{moz:official}&client=firefox)

Comment: @oers please see the screenshot above i have attached. that the error i got. hmm when removing the "extends SeleneseTestCase" it will cause an error, but when i alter it to "SeleneseTestBase" the deprecated will be gone, hmm however it seems doesn't works that too..

Answer (score 1):

i already solved my issue, thanks for you help.. i just exclude the PieChart.class, cause whenever i run the junit, since PieChart.class is a utility class, so it can't be run in ant.. on the xml i just exclude the class, `<exclude name = "PieChart.class" />` and just to make sure i just added `<exclude name="PieChart.java" />`

```
                <classpath refid="Igloo.path" />
                <batchtest todir="${Igloo.reportsDir}" fork="true">
                    <fileset dir="${Igloo.dest}">
                        <include name="ABMTLinks.class" />
                        <exclude name = "PieChart.class" />
                        <exclude name = "PieChart.java" />
                    </fileset>
                </batchtest>
            <formatter type="xml" />
            <classpath refid="Igloo.path" />
            </junit>

                <junitreport todir="${Igloo.reportsDir}">
                    <fileset dir="${Igloo.reportsDir}">
                        <include name="TEST-*.xml" />
                    </fileset>
                    <report todir="${Igloo.reportsDir}"/>       
                </junitreport>
        </target>
```