# Running groovy unit tests in ant for a java project

Tags: unit-testing, ant, groovy

I have a Java project with some unit tests written using JUnit. Recently some new unit tests have been added that are written in groovy (also using JUnit) as it's easier to make those 
more expressive and generally easier to read. It also allows us to use the spock framework.

The project is build and tested with *ant*.

Before the groovy classes were added unit tests were run using the following ant task:

```
<target name="test" depends="test-compile">
    <junit printsummary="yes">
        <classpath>
            <path refid="test.classpath"/>
        </classpath>
        <formatter type="plain"/>
        <batchtest fork="yes" todir="${test.dir}/report">
            <fileset dir="${test.dir}/unit" includes="**/*.java"/>
        </batchtest>
    </junit>
</target>
```

However, this approach does not work for groovy tests as those are in `*.groovy` files and the *[JUnit Ant task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html)*, understandably, does not recognise them in the `fileset`.

The alternative approach is to use `*.class` files for the `batchtest` `fileset` like this:

```
<batchtest fork="yes" todir="${test.dir}/report">
    <fileset dir="${test.dir}/${build.dir}">
        <include name="**/*Test*.class" />
    </fileset>
</batchtest>
```

This generates *false negatives* as closure class files are also included so a possible workaround is to exclude those files.

```
<batchtest fork="yes" todir="${test.dir}/report">
    <fileset dir="${test.dir}/${build.dir}">
        <include name="**/*Test*.class" />
        <exclude name="**/*$*.class" />
    </fileset>
</batchtest>
```

Is there a better way to identify test classes fo the *junit ant* task? Perhaps one based on reflection and the `@Test` attribute as manually listing all the test classes (which would work perfectly well) is not really a maintainable solution. Something like the `SpecClassFileSelector` from the [Spock framework](http://code.google.com/p/spock/).

Answer (score 3):

what about changing the include pattern to `*Test` rather than `*Test*`
as @jon-skeet suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/672466/junit-how-to-avoid-no-runnable-methods-in-test-utils-classes).

This way it will not match the anonymous closure classes.

you'll have to rename your existing classes and ask the developers to follow this pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-pg11094/

There's a groovyc ant taskdef for compiling the groovy test cases and running them.  The example there is Maven, but it shouldn't be too hard to adapt it to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks. I have seen this page before writing the question. My two proposed solutions actually do what the maven solution does - look at the classpath.

Answer (score -1):

Can't you just write something like this?

```
        <fileset dir="${test.dir}/unit" includes="**/*.java,**/*.groovy"/>
```

Comment: No, because it does not work. According to the JUnit ant task documentation: 
batchtest collects the included resources from any number of nested Resource Collections. It then generates a test class name for each resource that ends in .java or .class

Comment: I've been using Gradle lately. You should really take a look a it, it's so much easier and flexible than Ant, and especially than Maven. The Groovy plugin lets you build projects with Java and Groovy classes, as well as test using Groovy and Java.