# How to run selenium tests in Chrome browser?

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I have some tests using JUnit and Selenium, and I need to run it on the Chrome browser. I downloaded the Chrome driver, and configure my SetUp() as:

```
@Before
public void SetUp() throws Exception{
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    baseUrl = ;
    driver.get(baseUrl);    
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);//Wait 5 seconds to load the page
}
```

The ChromeDriver.exe are added in my "Referenced Libraries" folder.
**When I'll run the tests, the following error is displayed:**
java.lang.exception: No runnable methods

Anybody know how can I fix this?

**SOLUTION**

1º Add the chromedriver in the path of your computer.
2º Update your setProperty as: `System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\pedro_nazario\\Desktop\\ChromeDriver\\chromedriver.exe");`
The second parameter must be the way where is your Chromedriver.exe in my case, the chromedriver are in a folder on desktop.

**The most important thing, that you never forget**
When you'll run the tests, before, close your Chrome browser completely. Any chrome browser must be open before you run your tests. If have some chrome browser opened, the selenium will take a error in your screen.

Comment: If you change `ChromeDriver()` to `FirefoxDriver()` and run it again, do you get the same error?

Comment: No, in Firefox it's working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/getting-started), `webdriver.chrome.driver` should contain the path to the chromedriver executable:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/path/to/chromedriver");
```

Alternatively, you can add path to the chromedriver to the `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: @PedroHenrique are you sure the path to `chromedriver` is correct? Also, could you show the complete error traceback? Thanks.

Comment: @PedroHenrique it could also be unrelated to chromedriver, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/672466/junit-how-to-avoid-no-runnable-methods-in-test-utils-classes.

Comment: My ChromeDriver are added in my Referenced Libraries. The Error traceback is here: http://pastebin.com/2aDZUQSZ

Comment: @PedroHenrique yeah, it's not about chromedriver. Please show the complete code you have now. Thank you.

Comment: I have the same class, but using firefox driver, and it's working fine, but, in Chrome, isn't work.

Comment: @PedroHenrique please include the traceback and the complete code you have into the question - I'll delete the answer since it doesn't help. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah looking at your code on pastebin, you've copy-pasted `System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/path/to/chromedriver");` directly. What Alecxe was saying was to include that property but set the second arguement to your actual path - not to `/path/to/chromedriver` but something like `c:\user\myreferencelibrary\chromedriver.exe`

Comment: Hey guys, it's working now, i'll update the post with the solution, tks for everything

Comment: @PedroHenrique do you feel I should delete the answer, or you can mark it as accepted? I see that it is pretty close to what your real problem was. Thanks.