# Junit - Ignore on class level doesn't work

Tags: testing, junit, annotations

I'm using junit 4.12 and would like to ignore all test cases in class at once instead of adding ignore annotation before each method marked as test.
According to documentation it is possible to add @Ignore on class level.

```
@Ignore
public class BasicOperationsTest extends TestBaseClass{
```

I did it like above but it doesn't work - all test methods are executed.
When I add ignore before @Test method in this case annotation works and test is not executed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get Junit 4 to ignore a Base Test Class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461644/how-to-get-junit-4-to-ignore-a-base-test-class)

Comment: Are you sure you are using `org.junit.Ignore` and not some other `@Ignore` annotation ?

Comment: I'm sure because I don't have any other Ignore to import

Comment: And it's not a duplicate because this solution from linked post doesn't work

Comment: How do you run the tests? Which commands do you use? Posting your  `TestBaseClass` would also help.

Comment: Please post you `TestBaseClass`

Answer (score 0):

(Disclaimer: This is likely not OPs original issue, but it might be the issue of people who arrive here from google)

The problem for me was that I was using `@Ignore` with junit5, but in junit5/jupiter, the correct annotation is `@Disabled`, while `@Ignore` does nothing.

There is a subtle difference between the two in how the annotated tests get reported, but the usage is the same: https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/junit-ignore-test-cases/ 
namely, Junit5&Disabled will count and report the number of ignored *methods*, while junit4&Ignore will count and report the number of ignored *classes*. But since both work to skip the test in the class, I don't think most people care.