# Sonar: Add some tests to this class

Tags: java, unit-testing, sonarqube

I have an util class where I create Fake date for my unit test, I put it in test part of my Object:

```
public class FakeDataToTest {
  //.. fake objects
}
```

But Sonar give a Blocker, because this class doesn't contain unit test, in another word not have a method annotated `@Test`, the message of sonar is:

```
Add some tests to this class.
```

[image]

What is the clean way to avoid this ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47979801/5962766

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution in the [sonar doc](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/tag/tests/RSPEC-2187), it say:

> There's no point in having a JUnit TestCase without any test methods.
> Similarly, you shouldn't have a file in the tests directory with
> **"Test"** in the name, but no tests in the file. Doing either of these things may lead someone to think that uncovered classes have
> been tested.
>
> This rule raises an issue when files in the test directory have "Test"
> in the name or implement TestCase but don't contain any tests.
>
> Supported frameworks:
>
> - JUnit3
> - JUnit4
> - JUnit5
> - TestNG
> - Zohhak
> - ArchUnit

---

All you should to do is to use a class name without `Test` in my case I used `FakeData`, else it will considered as a unit test.

Comment: can you add link to the doc/quote?

Comment: @user7294900 yes, check now

Comment: If you also put Test file in test directory, rule make sense

Comment: Yes this is the reason, I put the FakeDataTest in the test directory

Comment: I believe, the idea is not to have a class inside `test` directory ending with the term `Test` which makes a perfect sense. **This rule raises an issue when files in the test directory are named *Test, *Tests, or *TestCase or implement TestCase but don't contain any tests.**

Comment: @Prashant I don't know where I'm not clear, yes the problem happen because I put a class where the name is end with **Test** in the test which not contain any test!

Comment: @Prashant test packages are for test related classes, like utilities and custom mocks. It's perfectly fine that `FakeData` is here, in its specific package

Answer (score 0):

If you are not interested in writing tests for this class, you can supress the Sonar rule by adding the @SupressWarnings annotation corresponding to the rule id (which you can fetch from your sonar configuration) :

```
@java.lang.SuppressWarnings("squid:<rule_id>")
```